# Remembering Checked Checkboxes using Display tag pagination

Tags: java, javascript, pagination, displaytag

I actually want to accomplish the same thing a user in

[Remembering checked checkboxes across pages - what's the best way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365757/remembering-checked-checkboxes-across-pages-whats-the-best-way)

asked. But not for php, I want it for java(Spring Portlet) and javascript.

I`m using pagination display tag and want to remember the checked checkbox while the user is navigating over the pages provided by pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the `org.displaytag.decorator.CheckboxTableDecorator`, which will add the Checkboxes to your paginated list. It requries two fields, Id and FieldName. Id should be one of the class member of the respective bean class, and you can give any FieldName to the field. You have to include this inside a form element. And the same form name has to be given in the DisplayTag's form attribute.

Please see the [displaytag examples](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-checkboxes.jsp) link for help